# execution catching priority

Tags: java, exception

I need to understand java exception handling priority.

I have a class Controller, having a class NodeManager having a class NameManager.
NameManager has a method:

```
public LriNode getLriNode(...) throws HttpErrorException
{
   if(condition)
     throw new HttpErrorException (status); 
}
```

the class NodeManager uses the previous method within the following

```
public void nodeWriter(...) throws HttpErrorException
{
            ...
    try
    {
        //this can throw an HttpErrorExeption
        lriNode = nameManager.getLriNode(resourceName);
        ...
    }       
    catch (HttpErrorException e)
    {
        if(e.getStatus().name().equals(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND))
        {
          //here can be thrown an HttpErrorExeption too
           do work
        }
        else
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

and finally the class Controller uses the previous method in the following

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.PUT, value="document/{name}")
public ModelAndView putDocument(@RequestBody String body, @PathVariable String name, HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request)
{
    Source source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(body));

    try
    {

        NodeManager.nodeWriter(...);
        return new ModelAndView(XML_VIEW_NAME, "document", document);
    }
    catch (HttpErrorException e)
    {
        response.setStatus(e.getStatus().value());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Well, that's the point: when NameManager throws a `HttpErrorException`, I expect the try-catch block within the NodeManger's `nodeWriter()` method to be executed to the exception. What it happens is that the control is returned to the Controller class and its try-catch block is executed. It seems that the `throws HttpErrorException` statement in the `nodeWriter()` method has a priority on the inner try-catch block.

Can anyone explain me such exception handling priority system?

Comment: as far as I know there is no such exception handling priority system. as you point out you can raise HttpErrorExeption in the catch statements of NodeWrite. I think that is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Throwable does not propagate outside of a try/catch block that handles that type of Throwable. Check the line numbers in the stack trace, and this will tell you exactly where the Exception originates. (Incidentally some java IDEs have an "analyze stacktrace" feature that allows you to click directly to the class and line number in question. I've never found much use for this, but the feature exists, so somebody must have found it useful.)

Comment: This is the fact: HttpErrorException is a custom exception I defined to handle Http communication trubles.

Comment: continues from the previous comment (5 minutes comment editing issue).

This is the fact: HttpErrorException is a custom exception I defined to handle Http communication issues. I am using Spring with its own RestTemplate and the methods used to contact the network entities belong to such class. Unluckily, these methods can throw a spring framework exception called Http**Client**ErrorException which I mistook for the one I defined.
In the end the whole issues is about my distraction.
I thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you mention that your `Controller` is handling the exception.  Well, in the `nodeWriter()` method call, your catch suggests that a `HttpErrorException` can be rethrown.

```
public void nodeWriter(...) throws HttpErrorException
{
            ...
    try
    {
        //this can throw an HttpErrorExeption
        lriNode = nameManager.getLriNode(resourceName);
        ...
    }       
    catch (HttpErrorException e)
    {
        if(e.getStatus().name().equals(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND))
        {
          //LOOK HERE!!! --> here can be thrown an HttpErrorExeption too
        }
        else
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

If this can rethrow an `HttpErrorException`, then the `Controller` that called `nodeWriter()` will then handle that exception.